# VBA: Build a Table by (Copy/Paste) by Using Criteria to Select Rows, Then Specifiy Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to build a table on one Excel Sheet "Ship" by pulling data from another excel sheet "Efficiency." The row data on the "Efficiency" sheet is categorized by "Shipped", "Leave", "Import" and "Export".
Each category (shipped, leave, import, export) has several items and they're in no specific order. The table on the "Efficiency" sheet occupies columns A:H, and starts at row 2; the length can vary.
I want to be able to search the rows for "Shipped" and copy columns A, D:F and H of the matching rows and paste them beginning at cell B4 of the "Ship" sheet. Can anyone help me please?

Sub Ship()

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$201").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Shipped"
' this is looking in a specific range, I want to make it more dynamic

Range("A4:A109").Select
'This is the range selected to copy, again I want to make this part more dynamic

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("A4:A109,D4:F109,H4:H109").Select
Range("G4").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Ship").Select
Range("B4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

End Sub

Comment: use VLOOKUP or OFFSET. May i know in which column the categorized data Shipped, Leave, Import and Export in

Comment: Column B is where these are categorized

Comment: @Krish, please find the code answered

Comment: I tried it. From reading it, it is supposed to work but I am not getting any tangible results that I can adapt to

Comment: @Krish, what result you get. Can you please elaborate

Comment: No results show up

Comment: did you run my code?. its working at my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has been tested based on your the information as given in your question:

```
Sub Ship()

Dim wsEff As Worksheet
Dim wsShip As Worksheet

Set wsEff = Worksheets("Efficiency")
Set wsShip = Worksheets("Shipped")

With wsEff

    Dim lRow As Long
    'make it dynamic by always finding last row with data
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'changed field to 2 based on your above comment that Shipped is in column B (the code you posted has 4).
    .Range("A1:H" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Shipped"

    Dim rngCopy As Range
    'only columns A, D:F, H
    Set rngCopy = Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("D:F"), .Columns("H"))
    'filtered rows, not including header row - assumes row 1 is headers
    Set rngCopy = Intersect(rngCopy, .Range("A1:H" & lRow), .Range("A1:H" & lRow).Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    rngCopy.Copy

End With

wsShip.Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: I get a runtime error '1004': No cells were found
This happens at the line
'Set rngCopy = Intersect(rngCopy, .Range("A1:H" & lRow), .Range("A1:H" & lRow).Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)'

Comment: @Kish - make sure the `AutoFilter` line is filtering on the right column for your data. I based it on your example, but if the example is not correct, it will show no results in the filter. Based on the comment that you made, the `Field` argument should be `2` in the `AutoFilter` method.

Comment: Yes, it runs better, it was at 4. I will fine tune it to get exactly what I need. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
Sub runthiscode()
    Worksheets("Efficiency").Select
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    startingrow = 4
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 2) = "Shipped" Then
            cella = Cells(i, 1)
            celld = Cells(i, 4)
            celle = Cells(i, 5)
            cellf = Cells(i, 6)
            cellh = Cells(i, 8)
            Worksheets("Ship").Cells(startingrow, 2) = cella
            Worksheets("Ship").Cells(startingrow, 5) = celld
            Worksheets("Ship").Cells(startingrow, 6) = celle
            Worksheets("Ship").Cells(startingrow, 7) = cellf
            Worksheets("Ship").Cells(startingrow, 9) = cellh
            startingrow = startingrow + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @krish, its working at my end. May i know where did you place the above code?

Comment: I tried to run in VBA, it looks like a code written in MATLAB